# XCode 5.1.1 initWithNibName not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
#import "ABCViewController.h"

@interface ABCViewController ()

@end

@implementation ABCViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
   {
      Ask = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      Anw = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
    return self;
}
```

When I run this program, I found both `Ask` and `Anw` are null. I think it is because `initWithNibName` is not called. How do I fix this?

Comment: How do you **found both Ask and Anw are null**?

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside initWithNibName and run the app. Are you sure it is not being called? Also - where do you define Ask and Anw?

Comment: If you are using StoryBoard, do init stuff in `initWithCoder` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `StoryBoard` then there is a possibility that it would not be called, Try adding your code to `viewDidLoad` method.